# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, gradlew

I just import an existing android project and wanted to run a gradle task from terminal.

But however I'm always getting following exception for this project:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

I saw already several answers to the same problem, but they don't really help me.

Just to be sure my Android Studio is working right, I tried to open another project. There everything worked fine. And on the first look all settings of the project are the same.

I didn't installed gradle on my mac but using default gradle wrapper of the android studio instead.

Maybe any of you have a solution?

Comment: run this `gradle--stacktrace`

Comment: since I didn't install gradle that didn't work

Answer (score 11):

A really stupid thing, but ... maybe it helpes someone else.

The gradle wrapper folder I've got didn't contain gradle-wrapper.jar

I'm not sure it's a right solution, but I added it manually from another project and now it works.

Comment: Not stupid at all, was trying to find a solution for hours, this way solved it in a minute, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case nothing else helps, for a similar issue I cleaned up (i.e. deleted) the folders .gradle\caches and .gradle\wrapper\dists. Seems like something was broken in there.

My original error message was "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain" when trying to run the gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change distribution url in gradle-warper.properties file to updated version  like below

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip